# Convert curl (with --data-urlencode) to ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

I am trying to convert the following curl command to ruby using `net/http` but I haven't figured out how to pass in the `--data-urlencode script@files/jql/events.js` part of the command.

```
curl https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/jql -u <apikey>: --data-urlencode script@files/jql/events.js
```

Using `net/http` I had the following...

```
uri = URI.parse("https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/jql")
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
request.basic_auth("<apikey>", "")

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https") do |http|
http.request(request)
end
```

Is there anyway to do this? If not within `net/http` then maybe using another gem?

Comment: haven't tried it, but https://github.com/taf2/curb sounds like it could work for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mixpanel has it's [official ruby gem](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-ruby)
I didn't actually work with it, but I assume it have all needed methods.

But if you don't like to use it, you may use [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) an awesome HTTP client library for Ruby.

I made a simple example with it. Please have a look:

```
class MixpanelClient
  def initialize(url = "https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/jql", api_key = "ce08d087255d5ceec741819a57174ce5")
    @url = url
    @api_key = api_key
  end

  def query_data
    File.read("#{Rails.root}/lib/qry.js")
  end

  def query_params
    '{"from_date": "2016-01-01", "to_date": "2016-01-07"}'
  end

  def get_events
    resp = Faraday.new(url: @url, ssl: { verify: false }) do |faraday|
      faraday.request  :url_encoded
      faraday.response :logger
      faraday.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter
      faraday.basic_auth(@api_key, "")
    end.get do |req|
      req.params['script'] = query_data
      req.params['params'] = query_params
    end

    raise MixpanelError.new("Mixpanel error") unless resp.status == 200
    JSON.parse(resp.body)
  end
end

class MixpanelError < StandardError; end
```

Here is the result:

```
[1] pry(main)> m = MixpanelClient.new
=> #<MixpanelClient:0x007fc1442d53b8 @api_key="ce08d087255d5ceec741819a57174ce5", @url="https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/jql">
[2] pry(main)> m.get_events
I, [2016-06-09T09:05:51.741825 #36920]  INFO -- : get https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/jql?params=%7B%22from_date%22%3A+%222016-01-01%22%2C+%22to_date%22%3A+%222016-01-07%22%7D&script=function+main%28%29%7B+return+Events%28params%29.groupBy%28%5B%22name%22%5D%2C+mixpanel.reducer.count%28%29%29+%7D
D, [2016-06-09T09:05:51.741912 #36920] DEBUG -- request: Authorization: "Basic Y2UwOGQwODcyNTVkNWNlZWM3NDE4MTlhNTcxNzRjZTU6"
User-Agent: "Faraday v0.9.2"
I, [2016-06-09T09:05:52.773172 #36920]  INFO -- Status: 200
D, [2016-06-09T09:05:52.773245 #36920] DEBUG -- response: server: "nginx/1.9.12"
date: "Thu, 09 Jun 2016 03:05:52 GMT"
content-type: "application/json"
transfer-encoding: "chunked"
connection: "close"
vary: "Accept-Encoding"
cache-control: "no-cache, no-store"
access-control-allow-methods: "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
access-control-allow-headers: "X-PINGOTHER,Content-Type,MaxDataServiceVersion,DataServiceVersion,Authorization,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since"
=> [{"key"=>["Change Plan"], "value"=>186}, {"key"=>["View Blog"], "value"=>278}, {"key"=>["View Landing Page"], "value"=>1088}, {"key"=>["login"], "value"=>1241}, {"key"=>["purchase"], "value"=>359}, {"key"=>["signup"], "value"=>116}]
```

A set `ssl: {verufy: false}` because Faraday need addtitional workaround to work with ssl certificates: https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/wiki/Setting-up-SSL-certificates

Comment: This is great! It works perfectly. Thanks for your help on this! Apparently, I don't have enough reputation to up vote your response.

Comment: @Manpreet Komal, glad was able to help :) You can just mark my answer as right. That would be enough.